# Proving that motion of an $n$ dimensional oscillator can be written as a linear combination of "sine waves"

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, equilibrium, linear-algebra, differential-equations

Here is a related question which might provide some context: [LINK](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3196600/proving-that-any-solution-to-the-differential-equation-of-an-oscillator-can-be-w).

Let's consider an oscillator with equation of motion in $n$ dimensions:
$$
\frac{d^2}{dt^2} \vec{x} = K \vec{x}.
$$

Given that $\vec x=0$ is a **stable** equilibrium, how can I show that the system will oscillate in sine waves? In other words, how to prove that the system will **not** behave like $x=\sinh t$? More precisely, how can I show that the $y_i$ in the answer in the link above will be sine waves?

As the answer in the link above suggest, to prove the solution to the DE has sine wave pattern, I need to prove that $K$ is symmetric with **negative** eigenvalues (see also the comment below the answer).

What about the case that $\frac{d^2}{dt^2} \vec{x} = f(\vec{x})$, where $f(\vec{x})$ doesn't have to be linear, but can be approximated linearly by $K \vec{x}$? If $\vec x=0$ is a stable equilibrium, must the eigenvalues of $K$ be negative OR zero?

I hope I am clear. Please tell me if I am not expressing myself clealy.

Answer (score 0):

In the case that $K\vec{x}$ is exact rather than an approximation, note that if the equilibrium is stable, work done of a virtual displacement $\delta \mathbf x$ must be negative. So, 
$$
\text{work done}=F.d\propto (K\delta \mathbf x).\delta \mathbf x=\delta \mathbf x^T K\delta \mathbf x<0.
$$
So $K$ is negative definite, and all eigenvalues are negative.

If $K$ is just an approximation of $f$, then we may only have $\leq$ instead of $<$. So you can still show that it is non-positive.

But why $K$ must be symmetric?